# Getting P0101 after replacing MAF sensor

Tags: maf

I am getting P0101 after replacing my MAF sensor. The freeze frame, which is the diagnostic reading app report at the time the code came in reports the following related metrics:

```
04 Calculated Engine Load Value 54.5 % 
05 Engine Coolant Temperature 81 °C, 178 °F 
06 Short Term Fuel Trim Bank 1 0.0 % 
07 Long Term Fuel Trim Bank 1 21.1 % 
08 Short Term Fuel Trim Bank 2 0.0 % 
09 Long Term Fuel Trim Bank 2 18.8 % 
0C Engine RPM 2128 rpm 
0D Vehicle Speed 92 km/h, 57 MPH 
10 Mass Air Flow Rate 29.23 g/s, 3.87 lb/min 1
15 O2 Bank 1 - Sensor 2 - Short Term Fuel Trim 99.2 % 
15 O2 Bank 1 - Sensor 2 - Oxygen Sensor Voltage 0.700 V 
19 O2 Bank 2 Sensor 2 (Bank 3 Sensor 2) Short Term Fuel Trim 99.2 % 
19 O2 Bank 2 Sensor 2 (Bank 3 Sensor 2) Oxygen Sensor 0.485 V
```

Could the MAF rate of 29.23 g/s, 3.87 lb/min be the reason for the code? Right now, when I accelerate the RPM to about the same (~2100), I get something like 1.1-1.2 lb/min? What could be the reason this happened? Vacuum leak somewhere along the air intake?

RELATED:

[P0171 -- System Lean Bank 1](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/92537/p0171-system-lean-bank-1)

[How to troubleshoot P0101 -- mass air flow?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/90521/how-to-troubleshoot-p0101-mass-air-flow)

Comment: See if [any of these readings](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WC7cZt1wincbjaOcMVHdNR6lUnj7EQ89op8jrSjp8lA/edit#gid=2131375586) match the vehicle you're looking at. Check to see if the g/s reading is anything close to what you're seeing. This could eliminate an issue which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 those look like very low MAF rates in the spreadsheet

Comment: Could be a defective part or maybe even just dirt in the connector causing high resistance.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven -- MAF sensor connector?

Comment: Yes, the plug that the MAF sensor uses to connect to the wire. You unclipped it to uninstall and then clipped the new MAF into it... Unless you had to splice the wires.

Comment: Freeze frame data shows both banks are running lean. Dirty or faulty maf sensor and a fuel pump are common to both banks. Have you checked your fuel pressure?